# Toggle href/attribute value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, href, attr

I'm trying to toggle the href value of an element on click. This is what I have so far:

```
$('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') == '#wwd-extra-content' ? '#wwd-section' : '#wwd-extra-content');
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<a class="smooth-scroll wwd-extra-content-trigger" href="#wwd-extra-content"><span></span></a>
```

But it doesn't seem to update on click.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Doesn't seem to update the href? http://jsfiddle.net/MHezU/

Comment: Worked fine in a fiddle I create when I changed the selector since your example has no ancestors with `.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MHezU/1/. Does the link in your actual code have ancestors with those classes?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Are you making sure the DOM is loaded before you attach your click handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making sure the DOM is loaded prior to attaching your click event handler?

```
$(function(){
    $('.wwd-content-container .wwd-content-each .wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
        $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') == '#wwd-extra-content' ? '#wwd-section' : '#wwd-extra-content');
    });
});
```

Comment: It was, but either the cache was throwing everything off; or it's just suddenly worked. Nonetheless, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

**From your code**

Just use `.wwd-extra-content-trigger`

`$('.wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') == '#wwd-extra-content' ? '#wwd-section' : '#wwd-extra-content');
});`

Comment: Why, what's wrong with the hierarchy the OP posted? Perhaps he needs that specific chain of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') == '#link1' ? '#link2' : '#link1');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

#### Edit

Originally misread OPs code.  I didn't notice that there were spaces between your classes.

Try changing your JavaScript to:

```
$('.wwd-content-container, .wwd-content-each, .wwd-extra-content-trigger').click(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') == '#wwd-extra-content' ? '#wwd-section' : '#wwd-extra-content');
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismborland/g5uxj/)

Comment: `You're selecting objects with ALL of the following classes`... well thats totally untrue.

Comment: If there weren't any spaces between the class names, that would be true. But since there are spaces, it's looking for descendents.